# Heroku: deploy Rails API + React fronend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, reactjs

I am using `react-redux-starter-kit` for the frontend and Rails 4.x version for the backend. During development, `koa` webserver was serving frontend at `localhost:3000` while `puma` was serving Rails at `localhost:5000`. Now I need to deploy these two to production (Heroku), and I am not sure how it works.

1. Rails lives in the root directory `/`
2. React lives in `/front` and I could compile the React app into `/front/dist/`

Now, how do I make `puma` serve whatever that's in `front/dist/` while also making sure that it serves Rails?

In other words:

1. http://mywebsite.com/ should serve the bundled React app
2. http://mywebsite.com/api/ should serve the Rails app

In development, the following setting works perfectly but I am running two different servers

1. http://localhost:3000 serves the React app (unbundled)
2. http://localhost:5000/api serves the Rails app.

This [blog post](http://fredguest.com/2015/03/06/building-a-stateless-rails-api-with-react-and-twitter-oauth/) goes in detail about deployment, but the missing part is how the React app is served at http://mywebsite.com.

Comment: To be honest, you have this fairly messed up.  I firmly believe that these are two different apps serving on two different boxes.  Right now you're deploying them from the same repository and that's probably not what you want to do.  You're going to need some CORS and you're going to need two different repos pointing at two different Heroku instances.